# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}

Tags: android

i am getting an fatal exception like

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Given caller package android is not running in process ProcessRecord
```

in an class which extends AtivityGroup trying to start another activity as bellow

```
View view = ((ActivityGroup) a).getLocalActivityManager().startActivity( "ReferenceName",
          intent.addFlags(
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
          a.setContentView(view);
```

which gives the above exception,

so i tried with usual way of starting Activity as bellow and it works fine.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    a.startActivity(intent)
```

i need another activity within same tab where i need the 1st method, can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: where do you start your activity from ?

Comment: from another class function which receives activity as argument

Comment: which context? an activity, a service, what?

Comment: class A extents Activitygroup calls a function in class B, from a function in class B i am trying to start another activity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using TabActivity and GroupActivity is deprecated and we can get the same effect by using TextView also :)